# python: how to decide the distance between two interpolated points?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I want to interpolated points from a set of known points. python provides a useful module [scipy.interpolate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx). However, how can I decide the distance between two interpolated points? For example, I would like the distance between interpolation points to be 2, how can I implement it?

For example, for the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi+np.pi/4, 2*np.pi/8)
y = np.sin(x)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)
xnew = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, np.pi/50)
ynew = interpolate.splev(xnew, tck, der=0)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(x, y, 'x', xnew, ynew, xnew, np.sin(xnew), x, y, 'b')
plt.legend(['Linear', 'Cubic Spline', 'True'])
plt.axis([-0.05, 6.33, -1.05, 1.05])
plt.title('Cubic-spline interpolation')
plt.show()
```

I would like the distance between the interpolated point to be 2:

```
dis = [xnew(2)-xnew(1), ynew(2)-ynew(1)]
norm(dis) = 2
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to provide a code. Also what do you mean with distance to be 2. Use every second point? No one can help you without more information.

Comment: Yes. Please, provide us with a sample of input (points) and desired output.

Comment: Look for `arange` here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation-in-1-d-procedural-interpolate-splxxx

Comment: sorry for the confusing description. I have edited the question. @Joe , the arange can only decide the number of the interpolated point, rather than the distance between interpolated point.

Comment: the third parameter is the step size `np.arange(0, 100, 3)`. If you need a certain number of values you could write a function that calculates the second parameter (end) based on the step size. e.g. `n = 40;    stepsize = 3;        np.arange(0, n * stepsize, stepsize)`